# Xpath extraction between two nodes

Tags: xpath, google-sheets

I have several web pages that have the following structure

```
<div id="w_33086" class = "eight columns">
<h2 id="about">About<span itemprop="name">Name of Place</span></h2>
<p style="margin-top: 0px;">
.
.
.
<p class="contactAdvisor"><a href="http://www.example.com/contact">
```

The text and markup between the two paragraphs is quite variable as it is created through individual users. In some cases it includes markup and in some cases it does not. When it does include markup, the mark up can be quite variable.

I'm trying to select all of the text and markup between these two `<p>` but have not been successful.

The best result I've achieved comes from //div[id='w_33086']/node()

However, that is dropping the `<p>` tags when those are present. It also picks up the `<h2>` tag and the `<p class="contactAdvisor">` that I would rather exclude.

I'm using Google Sheets (and or Screaming Frog) to apply the xpath

Comment: Are you trying to select text and markup that is a *child* of the first `<p>`, or is a following sibling of it? And, is the second `<p>` a child or sibling of the first?

Comment: Can you give an example "dropping the `<p>` tags"? It doesn't fit the scenario you seem to have described, but the description is ambiguous. Please give exact input, expected result, and actual result.

Answer (score 0):

If the two `<p>` elements are siblings of each other, then you could try

```
//div[id='w_33086']/p[@style="margin-top: 0px;"]/
   following-sibling::node()[following-sibling::p[@class="contactAdvisor"]]
```

This is assuming that there is only one `<p>` under `<div id="w_33086">` that has the `style` or `class` attribute value (respectively) that we're using to identify them.

Please note that XPath does not select any "markup". It selects nodes such as text nodes, elements (which have descendants attached), and attributes. Those nodes can be serialized as markup, but that's not XPath's business.